# Scrape a web page with PHP and Goutte by launching a pthread for each link to be followed

Tags: php, web-scraping, pthreads, goutte

I have been trying to implement a scraper using PHP and Goutte. Everything works fine if I use only one thread and scrape everything sequentially. In order to speed up the process I was hoping to:

1. Load the initial page which contains several links to pages that need to be scraped and also links for paging.
2. Launch a different pthread for each link that needs to be scraped so that the scraping can occur in parallel.
3. Once all pthreads for that page have been launched from the main thread, the main thread would navigate to the next page and repeat the launching of the pthreads for all the links in that page.

Of course I was planning on a mechanism to ensure the amount of threads running at one time did not exceed a certain number.

In any case my problem is currently related with providing the Goutte client and the link to follow to each thread.

Apparently the Goutte client is not serializable and cannot be passed as is in the thread constructor and then cloned so that each thread has its own instance of the Goutte client.

I get the following error when trying to assign the thread with a clone of the original client:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 
>       'Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed' in 
>       D:\users\Oriol\workspace\TravellScrapper\pagescrapers\baseScraper.php on line 15

This is the code of the Thread class that tries to clone the Goutte client in its constructor.

```
class baseScrapper extends Thread{

  public function __construct($client,  $link){
    $this->client = new Client();
    $this->client = clone $client;
    $this->link = $link;
    threadThrottle::addThread();
  }

  public function run(){
    $this->crowler = $this->client->click($this->link);
  }

  public function __destruct(){
    threadThrottle::removeThread();
  }
}
```

Any suggestion on how this could be accomplished? I need to duplicate the Goutte client in each thread so that it contains all the session information and that I can click on the link.

Comment: you do this you'll end up taking down the site. This is why they call crawlers crawlers...because unless they *crawl* i.e. slowly they cause problems and are seen as malicious

Comment: better to read page 1, save links into a database. wait...go to database, read a link, get page, save its links to database. wait...then *slowly* get each link over time

Comment: I was not intending to have that many threads running at the same time. Just a few to speed up the process slightly. Anyhow ... the question on how to pass a non serializable object to a thread and clone it is still open-

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the reason for using pthreads is to perform data communications asynchronously...

Goutte essentially adapts Guzzle onto the `Symfony\Component\BrowserKit`.  While doing so it abstracts the asynchronous capabilities of the library away.

You can use [GuzzleHttp\Pool](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Pool.php) to make multiple [concurrent requests](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#concurrent-requests)

An example copy & pasted from the docs)

```
use GuzzleHttp\Pool;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;

$client = new Client();

$requests = function ($total) {
    $uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:8126/guzzle-server/perf';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
        yield new Request('GET', $uri);
    }
};

$pool = new Pool($client, $requests(100), [
    'concurrency' => 5,
    'fulfilled' => function ($response, $index) {
        // this is delivered each successful response
    },
    'rejected' => function ($reason, $index) {
        // this is delivered each failed request
    },
]);

// Initiate the transfers and create a promise
$promise = $pool->promise();

// Force the pool of requests to complete.
$promise->wait();
```

Goutte is a great piece of software; but, it sounds like for your particular use case, asynchronous data communications, you would be better served by using the underlying libraries (Guzzle, DomCrawler, or even \DomDocument) individually.

Answer (score 1):

Using a more recent version of pthreads will cause the error to go away, Closures support is included in the most recent version.

A Thread-Per-Request model is not ideal, it doesn't really sound like threads are ideal; If all you want to do is download a bunch of stuff concurrently, then use nbio.

As others have mentioned, a bot that scans as you have suggested it should will soon be banned from whatever website you intend to scrape.

Comment: I just installed pthreads in my environment, so I am quite sure that I am using the latest version but I will double check.

Comment: Regarding the nbio ... I find no references in google with documentation to check it out ... could you refer me to a specific website?

Comment: By the way Joe, I have read in another thread a comment from you stating that "Zend does not allow you to serialize closure objects.

So it's not something you should try to work around, possibly at some time in the future Zend will allow serialization of Closures, pthreads will not require changes at that time." Will using the latest pthreads be enough?

Comment: I have checked the pthreads version I am using ... it is 2.0.9. in windows I have seen there is a version 2.0.10

Comment: Acording to the change log, version 2.0.9 is the one in which support for closures was added. So I don't understand why am I still getting the error..

Comment: Zend still doesn't support it, but decided to work around it, we don't really need it to be serialized (in the PHP sense of the word).

Comment: But if I am correct version 2.0.9 of pthreads should already support closures but is still giving the error. Any suggestion?